# Volt templating (Phalcon) - What is better between "partial" and "include" to use in a loop?

Tags: phalcon, volt

I see there are 2 options to include a "partial" template within a template (using Volt, Phalcon PHP framework) Documentation: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#view-integration

What is better between "partial" and "include" to use in a loop (about 100x)? In terms of performance / memory usage?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#partial-vs-include. Gives you a pretty good idea of the pros / cons of each function.

If the data is changing frequently then use partial, if the data is static then use include.

Comment: @honerlawd I read that part in the doc, but where have you seen that if it's static I should use include, and if it's dynamic I should use partials?

Comment: "‘Partial’ is better if the content that you have to include changes frequently". What I have to include is exactly the same template from the same file but with different variables. If it's the same file, maybe it just has to be loaded in memory/compiled once instead of being loaded every time in the loop. To me this is unclear as to which option is better in my case. I'll do some tests and see with the results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the variables change then it is dynamic. A file is not static if the contents of the file change.

Basically partial is better for what you are trying to do. Include copies the code into the file on compile. So everytime you change the variables it would have to recompile the template and insert it. Partial compiles to a function ```$this->partial()``` and is executed by the php interpreter which is faster in the context you are trying to use it.

Comment: @honerlawd Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@honerlawd answered my question in a comment.

It is better to use partial in a loop.

> Basically partial is better for what you are trying to do. Include
>   copies the code into the file on compile. So every time you change the
>   variables it would have to recompile the template and insert it.
>   Partial compiles to a function $this->partial() and is executed by the
>   php interpreter which is faster in the context you are trying to use
>   it.